# unexpected token in case of conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this unexpected token error in conditional rendering .However it looks fine to me but couldn't figure out what is going wrong .

```
{isAdd===true? 
      countries.map(item=>{
           return(
                 <MenuItem key={item.iso2} value={item.iso2}>{item.name}</MenuItem>
           );
      }))
      :
      return (
            <MenuItem key={101} value={101}>{'Country1'}</MenuItem>
      );
}
```

Comment: `return` cannot be parsed as an expression.

Comment: I could not understand this .Can you please be a little more clear ?

Comment: you have multiple closing brackets, in the map method
`countries.map(item=>{
           return(
                 <MenuItem key={item.iso2} value={item.iso2}>{item.name}</MenuItem>
           );
      })`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add return on the outside of the component (Assuming this is at the top of the `render()` function):

```
return isAdd===true ? 
      countries.map(item=> (
          <MenuItem key={item.iso2} value={item.iso2}>{item.name}</MenuItem>
      ))
      :
      <MenuItem key={101} value={101}>{'Country1'}</MenuItem>;
```

If it's nested in the component, simply just include `{` brackets to treat it like a variable:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {isAdd===true ? 
                countries.map(item=> (
                    <MenuItem key={item.iso2} value={item.iso2}>{item.name}</MenuItem>
                ))
                :
                <MenuItem key={101} value={101}>{'Country1'}</MenuItem>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue with your return statement.
Try this...

```
var returnItem;
{isAdd===true? 
      countries.map(item => {
        returnItem = <MenuItem key={item.iso2} value={item.iso2}>{item.name}</MenuItem>;
      })
      :
      returnItem =<MenuItem key={101} value={101}>{'Country1'}</MenuItem>;
}

return returnItem;
```